# HBase Split not working properly

Tags: hbase

I am trying to load huge amount of datadump into HBase. I have HBase set up with 8 Region servers. I got the suggestion that i need to presplit the table.

I used following command to create & pre-split the hbase table.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSplitter <table_name> UniformSplit -c 8 -f <column_family>.
```

I have one column family. I am preparing HBase rowkey based on 4 fields in the data. which are concatenated using "_" to form rowkey. I do not know the complete data, so i chose to using UniformSplit as above.

The problem is, i could only see all my requests going through only one region server in the HBase Master UI. How can i handle this situation.?

How can i make sure the requests & Data spread across all regions properly.?

Comment: Supposing that the splits worked, all your requests might go to one region because the keys are in the same range. To avoid that, you could either hash your keys, or manually split hbase

Comment: seeing an older post, you already have an answer ^^
don't hesitate to answer or close this post ;)